# How can I return the minimum key in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Is there an equivalent `min()` for the keys in an array?

Given the array:

```
$arr = array(300 => 'foo', 200 => 'bar');
```

How can I return the minimum key (`200`)?

Here's one approach, but I have to imagine there's an easier way.

```
function minKey($arr) {
    $minKey = key($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if ($k < $minKey) $minKey = $k;
    }
    return $minKey;
}
$arr = array(300 => 'foo', 200 => 'bar');
echo minKey($arr); // 200
```

Comment: Wow, what's with the downvotes? It's not a duplicate. Sure the answer was easy. I admit I should've known, but it still seems like a fair question to me.

Comment: @Ryan You got an upvote from me :)

Comment: Added the first strategy that came into my head to the question to help take off the off-topic hold. It seems silly now that I know about `array_keys()`, but this is what I was initially thinking when I asked the question. Would appreciate help (@Leri) reopening the question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo min(array_keys($arr));
```

Comment: This is an O(n) solution

Comment: I don't know what an O(n) is but one liners give me joy.

Answer (score 9):

Try with

```
echo min(array_keys($arr));
```

`min()` is a php function that will return the lowest value of a set. `array_keys()` is a function that will return all keys of an array. Combine them to obtain what you want.

If you want to learn more about this two functions, please take a look to [`min()` php guide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [`array_keys()` php guide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 1):

use `array_search()` php function.

```
array_search(min($arr), $arr);
```

above code will print `200` when you `echo` it.

For echoing the value of lowest key use below code,

```
echo $arr[array_search(min($arr), $arr)];
```

[**Live Demo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hdw-sk0)

Comment: @silkfire [**See Demo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hdw-sk0)  hit F9 or Press Run button..

Comment: @DipeshParmar It did not work with this array: `$arr = array(100 => 'ganesh', 300 => 'foo', 200 => 'bar');` Returned 200 but should have been 100. Why the upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

This also would be helpful for others,

```
<?php
//$arr = array(300 => 'foo', 200 => 'bar');
$arr = array("0"=>array('price'=>100),"1"=>array('price'=>50));

//here price = column name
echo minOfKey($arr, 'price');


function minOfKey($array, $key) {
    if (!is_array($array) || count($array) == 0) return false;
    $min = $array[0][$key];
    foreach($array as $a) {
        if($a[$key] < $min) {
            $min = $a[$key];
        }
    }
    return $min;
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = array(
300 => 'foo', 200 => 'bar'
);
$arr2=array_search($arr , min($arr ));
echo $arr2;
```