# Get closest city from array

Tags: php

I would like to create a function that returns the closest city (and the remaining distance to the city) from an array.

The numbers in the array represent the distance from the Starting point. `$currentPosition` is the current distance from the starting point.

E.g. at `$currentPosition` = `80`, `getCity()` should return [60, 'München']. But at the moment, it returns [-80, null];

Unfortunately, it does not work as planned.

So this is my code:

```
$cities= [
  [ 70, "Ingolstadt" ],
  [ 140, "München" ],
  [ 234, "Innsbruck" ],
  [ 443, "Venedig" ],
  [ 622, "Florenz" ],
  [ 835, "Rom" ],
  [ 973, "Neapel" ],
];

function getCity( $currentPosition) {
  for ($i=0; ;) {
    if ( $currentPosition > $cities[$i][0]  && $currentPosition < $cities[$i+1][0] ) {
      $i++;
    }else {
      $distance = $cities[$i][0] - $currentPosition;
      $city= $cities[$i][1];
      return array( $distance , $city);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the numbers? Are these distances along a planned path, with `$currentPosition` being your position along that path?

Comment: Ah, sorry! The numbers in the array represent the distance from the Starting point.

Comment: Your code currently seems to identify the "next" city on the path. Do you want that, or do you want it to be able to look backwards as well? For example, at position 80, should Ingolstadt be closest?

Comment: Prob a dupe of: [How can I return the minimum key in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735462/how-can-i-return-the-minimum-key-in-an-array)

Comment: Yes, looking for the next city is enough. So at position 80 the result should be [60, "München"]. The user should then see "60 kilometers to München"

Comment: Okay, in that case, just replace the `=>`s in your array with `,`. Your code is expecting `[70, "Ingolstadt"]`.

Comment: I did that, but the result is [-80, null]

Comment: The `$cities` variable is not available in your function. move the `$cities`in the function will help.

Comment: SubCore, you are right. Now it works! But why can't I use a general variable outside of the function?

Comment: Read more about [variable scope in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php 

    $cities = [
      [ 70, "Ingolstadt" ],
      [ 140, "München" ],
      [ 234, "Innsbruck" ],
      [ 443, "Venedig" ],
      [ 622, "Florenz" ],
      [ 835, "Rom" ],
      [ 973, "Neapel" ],
    ];


    $diff = 2147483647;
    $pos = 0;

    function getCity($currentPosition) {

      global $cities;
      global $diff;
      global $pos;

      for ($i=0; $i<count($cities); $i++) {
        if($cities[$i][0] > $currentPosition) {
            if(($cities[$i][0] - $currentPosition) < $diff) {
                $diff = $cities[$i][0] - $currentPosition;
                $pos = $i;
            }
        }
      }
      return "Nearest city is " . $cities[$pos][1] . " and the left distance is " . $diff;
    }

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1><?php echo getCity(80); ?></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I mean you can use next code:

```
<?php

$cities = [
  [ 70 => "Ingolstadt" ],
  [ 140 => "München" ],
  [ 234 => "Innsbruck" ],
  [ 443 => "Venedig" ],
  [ 622 => "Florenz" ],
  [ 835 => "Rom" ],
  [ 973 => "Neapel" ],
];


function getCity($cities, $currentPosition) {
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        $distance = abs(key($city)-$currentPosition);
        if (!isset($min) || $distance < $min) {
            $res = $city;
            $min = $distance;
        }
    }
    
    return $res;
}

$res = getCity($cities, 600);

var_export($res);
```

Here I [share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=84e82a143a8f0de70a4c92aa2cb754ca&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 1):

Move `$cities` into function. Like this:

```
function getCity( $currentPosition)  {
  $cities= [
    [ 70, "Ingolstadt" ],
    [ 140, "München" ],
    [ 234, "Innsbruck" ],
    [ 443, "Venedig" ],
    [ 622, "Florenz" ],
    [ 835, "Rom" ],
    [ 973, "Neapel" ],
  ];

  for ($i=0; ;) {
    if ( $currentPosition > $cities[$i][0]  && $currentPosition < $cities[$i+1][0] ) {
      $i++;
    }else {
      $distance = $cities[$i][0] - $currentPosition;
      $city= $cities[$i][1];
      print_r( array( $distance , $city));
      break;
    }
  }
}
getCity(80);
```

Will result as

```
Array ( [0] => 60 [1] => München )
```